# Can anyone help me to understand why oracle sql length function accepting numeric values or number datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried below query:

```
select length(12345) from dual;
```

it is giving results as below.

```
LENGTH(12345)
-------------
            5
```

Comment: I believe it is doing an implicit `cast` to a string. If you try `SELECT LENGTH(1234)` you will get `4`.

Comment: Adding to daShier's comment, the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm) indicate that "The LENGTH functions return the length of char" Thus, the Length function is expecting a char input. This could be the reason why it does an implicit cast

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, it is doing implicit conversion to the char.

If you want to see it.

```
Select length(012345) from dual
Output:
5

Select length('012345') from dual
Output:
6
```

You can see that implicit conversion removes 0 and gives 5 as an output if it is number.

But it gives output as 6 if we pass the same input as a string(no conversion happens).

Cheers!!